# How to decode *.rd file (RDCAM)

Tags: c#, vb.net, lasercutting

I'm working on interfacing a laser that has a ruida rdc6445g laser controller for industry 4.0.

I have seen that the laser and the PC that i connect to it use files with the *.rd extension for communication. The contents of the files are unreadable as-is.
Searching on the internet I have not found any way to decode them.
Does anyone know of an algorithm or library (C# or VB) that allows you to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ruida provides a SDK that includes documentation and sample code for communicating with Ruida laser controllers. The SDK includes a set of API functions that can be used to control the laser controller, including sending jobs and receiving status updates.

Here is a link to the Ruida SDK download page: http://www.rd-acs.com/download/list_56_1.html

The SDK is provided in C++, but you may be able to use it with C# or VB.NET by creating a wrapper.